# Joblib Parallel producing UnboundLocalError when called from external library

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib

This will be a bit hard to explain but I'll try my best. Please, if there is anything that requieres more clarification, do not hesitate to ask.

Basically, I've got the following function

```
def calcula_intersecciones_paralelizado2(conjunto_objetos_intersection):
    indices = np.arange(len(conjunto_objetos_intersection))
    indices.sort()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        roots_lists = Parallel(n_jobs=-3)(
            delayed(conjunto_objetos_intersection[i].solve_intersection)
            (number_of_points = N_points_intersection) for i in indices
        )
    roots_lists = np.array([ [row for row in roots_lists[m] if 0 <= row[1] <= 1 and 0 <= row[3] <= 1]  for m in range(len(roots_lists))], dtype=object)
    return roots_lists
```

In it, **conjunto_objetos_interseccion** is a list (or numpy array) of objects **Intersection**, which are a class I have defined myself.

This function, when defined and called from inside a notebook, works just fine, producing the desired output.

Now, I create another library that replicates the behaviour of the notebook, with the function **calcula_intersecciones_paralelizado2** among others and a class called **MachiningParameters** that takes the necessary inputs to reproduce the notebooks' behaviour. I call this new library *pm_executer.py* .

Now, when I import *pm_executer* and define the input parameters, the MachiningObject is created just fine, but when I try to call to a method on the class that calls to **calcula_intersecciones_paralelizado2** I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 1
----> 1 _ = machining_object.intersection_errors()

File ~/PhD/Codes/pm_executer.py:143, in MachiningParameters.intersection_errors(self)
    141 points, tri = self.surface.point_cloud()
    142 surface_tm = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices = np.array(points).T, faces = tri.triangles)
--> 143 int_error = IntersectionError(surface_discretized = surface_tm, list_of_curves = self.curvas_interseccion())
    144 return int_error

File ~/PhD/Codes/pm_executer.py:111, in MachiningParameters.curvas_interseccion(self)
    110 def curvas_interseccion(self):
--> 111     valroes_st = calcula_intersecciones_paralelizado2(self.objetos_interseccion)
    112     if type(valroes_st[0] == list):
    113         valroes_st = np.array([np.array(_) for _ in valroes_st], dtype = object)

File ~/PhD/Codes/pm_executer.py:42, in calcula_intersecciones_paralelizado2(conjunto_objetos_intersection)
     37 if __name__ == '__main__':
     38     roots_lists = Parallel(n_jobs=-3)(
     39         delayed(conjunto_objetos_intersection[i].solve_intersection)
     40         (number_of_points = N_points_intersection) for i in indices
     41     )
---> 42 roots_lists = np.array([ [row for row in roots_lists[m] if 0 <= row[1] <= 1 and 0 <= row[3] <= 1]  for m in range(len(roots_lists))], dtype=object)
     43 return roots_lists

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'roots_lists' where it is not associated with a value
```

My question is: why does all the code work fine when I define and run the parallelization function in the same place but it raises such error when called from outside and how can I fix it? Recall that the notebook where it works fine and *pm_executer* perform the exact same code. I don't add everything because I don't think that posting a bible here is necessary.

Thank you all in advance for your help!!

I am using python 3.11.0 on macOs Ventura 13.4 and joblib 1.2.0